# Tax in US or India

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, capital-gains-tax, dtaa

I am Indian citizen and living in US on H1B and have been paying taxes regularly in US. Now I want to start investing in Indian Stocks. If I make profits in Indian stocks where should I pay the taxes, is it in India or US.

Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 1):

From you question it looks like from tax point of view you are "Non-Resident" in India. And "Resident" in US.

From India tax point of view, any gains will be taxable in India.
US taxes global income, hence you would need to pay taxes in US as well. You can claim relief to the extent of taxes paid in India.